# 'GetPositionLowerLimits' and 'GetPositionUpperLimits' does not support get by ModelInstance as other functions

Tags: drake

What I find in Drake API is that 'GetPositionLowerLimits' and 'GetPositionUpperLimits' does not support get by ModelInstance as other functions.

Anybody knows how to query this when I have multiple robots and I am interested in the Lower and Upper Limits for every robot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can take the result of GetPositionLowerLimits (or GetPositionUpperLimits) and feed it through [GetPositionsFromArray](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#a9b8a17ef762452f820bdd351f8bb41b4) to select just one model instance at a time.

The [model instances](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#model_instances) documentation has some more information.

Comment: FYI in stack overflow there is a click to "Accept" the answer, which will then display the question as "answered" for anyone else who comes looking to be aware.